# How do I make a selected radio button change one piece of state based upon another radio button changing another piece of state?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, styled-components

I have a couple of components I am building and have run into a bit of a stumbling block.

The components start with a piano keyboard on which I can overlay different musical entities, like notes, intervals, chords, scales, etc...by passing the note names via a `notes={[]}` array prop into the `Keyboard` component. In this particular instance of the component I am then importing it into a `Scales` component in which I have added scale and note buttons, so I can overlay entire scales in this instance on top of the keyboard, which is all basically working. have a list of note names that I can click on and then overlay that scale on top of the keyboard, like so:

[The gif shows the current behavior of the `Scales` component, which is not quite correct yet...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBm55.gif)

In the gif you can see that the major and minor scale buttons change the state of the scale, which is then used by the note name buttons to change the state of the keyboard beneath it. But what I also want it to do is switch the currently selected scale when the major or minor button is clicked, but currently the note name buttons don't automatically react to the change in state in the major and minor buttons, but have to be clicked again to make the change occur.

What I want is to be able to just click the major and minor buttons and which ever note is selected will simply change from major to minor without having to re-click the selected scale note again, which is the current behavior.

So, in my Scales component I am using custom radio buttons like so, first to control the major and minor buttons:

```
<MajorInput
  type="radio"
  name="scale"
  id="major"
  label="major"
  value="major"
  checked={scale === 'major'}
  onChange={handleChange}
  onClick={() => setScale('major')}
/>
<MajorLabel
  whileHover={{ scale: 1 }}
  whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
  htmlFor="major"
>
  Major
</MajorLabel>
```

...then to control the note buttons, like so:

```
<NoteInput
  id="c"
  scale={scale}
  type="radio"
  name="notes"
  label="c"
  value="c"
  onClick={
    () => setNotes(
      scale === 'major' ? ['c1p', 'd1ma', 'e1ma', 'f1p', 'g1p', 'a1ma', 'b1ma'] :
      scale === 'minor' ? ['c1p', 'd1ma', 'eb1mi', 'f1p', 'g1p', 'ab1mi', 'bb1mi'] :
      ''
    )
  }
/>
<NoteLabel
  whileHover={{ scale: 1 }}
  whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
  scale={scale}
  htmlFor="c"
>
{
  scale === 'major' ? 'C' :
  scale === 'minor' ? 'C' :
  'C'
}
</NoteLabel>
```

...and the state is established via two useState hooks, like so:

```
const [ scale, setScale] = useState('')

const [ notes, setNotes] = useState([])
```

...then ultimately the imported `Keyboard` component receives it's `notes={notes}` prop from the notes buttons, like so:

```
<Keyboard octaves={'2'} notes={notes}/>
```

...so i don't really know how I could make the note buttons be aware or know about the scale buttons being clicked and then translate that information to the keyboards `notes` prop, which is where i am stuck now...

Here is a code sandbox of the the component:

https://codesandbox.io/s/scales-981uk

Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: You can use a state management tools like [redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux), for complex data flow between components, for now and further demand needs.

Answer (score 0):

I looked through your code.

The problem you have right now is that your note components are not rerendered and restyled when the major button is clicked. In React, you can use the change in props to trigger a rerender which will also restyle your notes.

I would suggest to put all your note inputs into a sub component. :

```js
// ./Scales.js

import NoteButtonBox from ./NoteButtonBox.js

//...

// important: pass scale as props. 
// Everytime scale changes, the note buttons are rerendered and restyled
sub component
  return (
    <Container>
      <ScaleButtonBox>
        {/* ... */}
      <ScaleButtonBox>
      <NoteButtonBox scale={scale} />
      {/* ... */}
```

```js
// ./NoteButtonBox.js


const NoteButtonBox = ({scale}) => {
   // Don't forget to also move 'const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);' into the 
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
  return { 
    /* return your styled notes based on props scale */
  }
}
```

---

EDIT

For situations where you need to access state across multiple sub components, you can use [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). Alternatively, you can use [React Redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react/) which accomplishes the same thing. I would suggest Comtext because it is a native part of React.

Breaking up your app into sub components might seem like unnecessary work but it is good practice to create many small components in React. React encourages composition like I suggest.

1. Create a `NotesStateContext` class.
2. You define the where it is needed `NotesStateContext.Provider`:

```js
      <NotesStateContext.Provider value="dark">
        <NoteButtonBox />
        </* All other components that need to access the state of your notes */>
      </NotesStateContext.Provider>
```

3. Get and update your state from the provider

Comment: hmmmm...running into a new issue with this approach, as I am passing `notes={notes}` into the keyboard component at the bottom of the Scales component, like so: ```jsx <Keyboard octaves={"2"} notes={notes} />```, but since I moved the notes state into a separate component I'm not sure how to get the `notes` state into the keyboard, which is how it knows which notes to change and how...

Comment: hmmmm...i realized something...the sate of the scale is being updated when i click on the scale buttons in all of the note buttons as well, but that does not automatically make the note buttons update the note state...so now I'm thinking that maybe the issue is that I need the note buttons to automatically update the notes state, but only if the note button is currently selected...

Comment: ...so when i switch scales with the scale button and i then click on the currently selected scale button it does indeed update to show the correct scale, but it's only after i click the scale button...so now I'm thinking that maybe the issue is that I need the note buttons to automatically update the notes state, but only if that particular note button is currently selected...

Comment: Yes, in React every state update triggers a rerender and should restyle your notes then.

Comment: ok, i'll try to wrap my head around context and see if i can make it work...it will take me some time, however, but hopefully it works XD

Comment: If my answer was helpful feel free to upvote my answer.

Comment: hmmmmm....but even if i useContext or redux I'm still not telling the `notes` state to update, no? Even if all state is accessible via context then I'm still only telling my note buttons to update the `notes` state `onClick`, but I'm still not telling them to update the `notes` state if they are selected && scale state changes, no? i think that's the part my brain is stuck on...gonna try context anyway, but i'm thinking this issue might persist...dunno yet, of course, so hope not 